# Обновление страницы в проекте mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Есть сайт в проекте mvc. И у меня по таймеру обновляется страница. В итоге когда таймер дотикает я юзаю `location.reload();`. В итоге обновляется как клиентская так и серверная часть, а как сделать что бы обновлялась только клиентская часть с теми же данными и не трогало бы серверную?

Comment: Когда отправляется запрос на сервер его обрабатывает определенный метод определенного контроллера. При каждой перезагрузке страницы вы отправляете запрос на сервер. Если вам нужно обновлять содержимое страницы в зависимости от событий на сервере, которые не зависят от клиента (к примеру новое сообщение в чате), советую смотреть в сторону `SignalR`.

Comment: Но зачем? Делайте ajax-запрос и самостоятельно (или с помощью какого-нибудь Vue-React) изменяйте то, что нужно актуализировать. На крайний случай - вам никто не мешает запрашивать HTML у сервера по ajax и рендерить его куда необходимо.

Comment: @free_ze ну как запросить html я нашёл, а как заного его разместить на странице?

Comment: ну хотя бы `parentElement.innerHTML = responseData;`